# Generate Dtos from EF code first classes without EDMX

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget

I have generated the EF classes from an existing database using 'Code First to Existing Database' option. This has generated all the classes beautifully but I want the Dto so that I can map eachone of these EF classes to a Dto...I tried EntitiesToDto but it requires that you have an EDMX and I dont and I was hoping to not have to create one

Is there some other addin or nuget package that could do it

EDIT: I created an EDMX file and then created another project and ran EntitiesToDtos and generated DTOs...this was ok but I was hoping to not have to create the EDMX

Comment: Do you mean something like Automapper? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper

Comment: no, I plan to use AutoMapper but I first need the Dto to map from the EF generated classes.

Comment: What's the problem with generating a temporary EDMX file? You'll likely need to do this just once.

Comment: yes, no real problem...was wondering if there was a better way of doing this. I am pretty sure I am not the only person to have ever had this 'situation' and I suspect someone somewhere has done something about it. Just wondering. But yes you're right - it is a bit of a 'first world' problem

Comment: You are not the only one, I struggle with the same issue. I hope someone that finds a good generate with share it with us.